# Terraform split subnets between 2 route tables

Tags: azure, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I have created a large amount of azure subnets with terraform, but i need to split them all between 2 route tables.

Currently i have my code like this, but of course the output from the resource is not a list, but objects.

```
resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "subnet-to-rt1" {
  for_each       = tolist(chunklist(azurerm_subnet.subnets, 255)[0])
  subnet_id      = (chunklist(azurerm_subnet.subnets, 20)[0])[each.key].id
  route_table_id = module.spoke.route_table_1
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "subnet-to-rt2" {
  for_each       = tolist(chunklist(azurerm_subnet.subnets, 20)[1])
  subnet_id      = (chunklist(azurerm_subnet.subnets, 20)[1])[each.key].id
  route_table_id = module.spoke.route_table_2
}
```

Edit:
Code to generate the subnets for clarity of the problem.
I provide the var.spoke_cidr in an slash /18 range to get /27's

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnets" {
  for_each             = toset(slice(cidrsubnets(var.spoke_cidr, [for v in range(20) : 9]...), 2, length(cidrsubnets(var.spoke_cidr, [for v in range(20) : 9]...))))
  name                 = "az-subnet-${index(slice(cidrsubnets(var.spoke_cidr, [for v in range(20) : 9]...), 2, length(cidrsubnets(var.spoke_cidr, [for v in range(20) : 9]...))), each.key)}"
  resource_group_name  = module.spoke.azure_rg.name
  virtual_network_name = module.spoke.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = [each.value]
}
```

The error code im getting for each route table association resource is

```
Invalid value for "list" parameter: list of any single type required.
```

Does anyone know how i can fix this route table associations
Thanks!

Comment: Fix what? You haven't provided much info? What are the values of all of your input variables? What errors do you get?

Comment: Im sorry if it's not clear. What im trying to do is take the large amount of subnets and associate half of each of them to each route table in the way that the first 10 should go to the first route table and the last 10 to the second route table, hence the chunklist attempt. I've added some code to show the generation of the subnets